# How to fire the same event in two different ways based on two criteria? (C#)

Tags: c#, events, multiple-instances

I might have got the words wrong to put forward this question. This is a tricky proposition and I want solution urgently :-(

I want to trigger `textBox1_KeyDown` in two different ways, but by keying down the same key based on some criteria. The code below would give more clarity.

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "x";
            } 
        }


        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                 textBox1.Text = "y";
            }
        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is when I press Enter button on textBox1, I want it to display "x" if there's no text in it. If there's some text in it, then I want the textbox to display "y" upon pressing Enter. When I do the way I coded above, both the procedures happen in one instance. That's, when I press Enter when the `textBox1` is blank it displays "y" (which should be "x"). That means it first displays "x" and then since the textbox has a quantity in it, the text becomes "y" as called by my code. How to Separate the two functions?? Like I want the textbox to show only "x" when its blank and I press Enter or it should show only "y" when its not blank and I press Enter.

I must be missing something silly.. Thanks.. Kindly gimme the code. I hardly understands technical terms..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for a start you could put `return;` in your deepest-nested `if` statements so that the next `if` doesn't get executed.

The other thing you can do is reverse the order of your conditions, so you test for `if (textBox1.Text != "")` at the top of your handler, rather than the bottom.

And finally, you could just use `else` between the two conditionals.

Comment: You seem to have given the most comprehensive of replies. let me ask you, what if I do all the three methods, would it make my case stronger? because where i deploy, it never gets executed properly. or would using all three backfire?

Comment: They wouldn't backfire if used collectively, but only one method would be necessary.

Answer (score 4):

That is because both if statements get executed. The first if statement executes and makes the text in the textbox not blank. This causes the next if statement to fire too. Simply doing this should fix it:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "")
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "x";
        } 
    }


    else if (textBox1.Text != "")
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
             textBox1.Text = "y";
        }
    }
}
```

note addition of "else" on second if statement.

Comment: Thanksss Matt Greer, it did solve the problem. Actually my code was something more complex. So When I tried this ( I did try), some other error caught up. I thought it could be that this else if method didnt work. Now I know the trouble wasnt with else if statement. To add to u, even `return` at the end of first loop would make this work

Answer (score 1):

Based upon what you have written there you could just flip the order of your if statements or make the second block an else or else if.

Comment: I'm afraid I am missing something in the problem you are having.  Everyone seems to have about the same answer so you may need to explain better what is happening.

Comment: It did work. thanksss.... Actually my code was something more complex. So When I tried this ( I did try), some other error caught up. I thought it could be that this else if method didnt work. Now I know the trouble wasnt with else if statement. To add to u, even `return` at the end of first loop would make this work

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like this, so I believe:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //determine if text is empty or otherwise equal to 'x'...
    if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty || textBox1.Text != "x")
    {
        //confirmed, set to 'x'...
        textBox1.Text = "x";
    }
    else //and a catch-all for y
    {
        //text wasn't empty or 'x', set to 'y'...
        textBox1.Text = "y";
    }
}
```

You could also achieve this in a shorthanded fashion using the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a):

```
//get a copy of the text
var value = textBox1.Text;
//set textbox value to 'x' if not empty or equal to 'x', otherwise 'y'
textBox1.Text = value == string.Empty || value != "x" ? "x" : "y";
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why not just add an else:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)    
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "")         
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "x";
        }
    }

    else if (textBox1.Text != "")
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "y";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanksss, it did solve the problem. Actually my code was something more complex. So When I tried this ( I did try), some other error caught up. I thought it could be that this else if method didnt work. Now I know the trouble wasnt with else if statement. To add to u, even `return` at the end of first loop would make this work